# Extracting value of specific tag by BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a simple python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('http://site.ir/')
out=response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(out)
for anchor in soup.select('body a'):
    print anchor.string
```

But the following error occurs:

```
  File "p.py", line 11, in <module>
for anchor in soup.select('body a'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

picture:
[image]

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer because you keep changing the question; it is no longer valid. You are using BeautifulSoup 3 tryng to use a BeautifulSoup 4 feature now.

Comment: have you looked at the content that is returned?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thank you... Could you put new answer? I don't know difference between   3 and 4, pardon for making you busy...

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham It returns me the error you can see in post,

Comment: I meant your html returned, I don't think it returns what you think it does

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham It just returns error... I want to extract all names in `a tag`.. I don't know how to resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

Install BeautifulSoup4 and do the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://site.ir/').content)
for anchor in soup.select('body a'):
    print anchor.text
```